# Does my concept follow a Microservice architecture?

Tags: php, magento, soa, single-page-application, microservices

I read [the article on Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) on Martin Fowler's page and find it quite interesting. Now I plan structuring an E-Commerce Web Application as proof-of-concept and am wondering if my concept is considered being a Microservice architecture.

The architecture consists of 3 components:

- a javascript based single page application, which sends AJAX requests to
- a server with a REST API which feeds JSON data received by calling other services (I think you call this behaviour API Gateway)
- 3 services: CatalogProvider, CustomersProvider, CheckoutProvider

For now the services all are API endpoints of a Magento (PHP) Shopsystem. In future I plan to then swap the providers with other systems.

So my questions are:

- MS are considered to be 'independently deployable'. I understand that in the world of JAVA we are talking about one JAR- or WAR-file, but how is a PHP service 'independently deployable'?
- Does my concept NOT follow the principles of a MS architecture, because the providers are all part of one big (Magento) system?

Thank you for reading. I'm happy for any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing that says you architecture is not a MS architecture just because you're using magento and PHP. But, you have to consider a few things:

- Think in terms of always being able to rewrite any of the services in any language and deploy somewhere the total system should just continue to work.

If your services are just transformation/interface very tightly linked to magento and you cannot simply rewrite them in java/C#/ruby easily, then I guess you do not have a MS architecture.

For PHP deployable artifacts, you typically have some packaging or versioning strategy around your service. Even though "deploy" in PHP is typically just swapping a folder of .php files. And you should not really share code/config between different services. You can even look at [deployment tools for PHP](http://deployer.in/) if you want to take an extra step.

Comment: `If your services are just transformation/interface very tightly linked to magento and you cannot simply rewrite them in java/C#/ruby easily, then I guess you do not have a MS architecture.` --> I did implement a Magento module, which extends the REST API and feeds the client with exactly the data structure it expects. So the service therefore surely is tightly linked to Magento as it for instance uses its models .. but i think u can still consider it a MSA, don't?

Comment: @Rouzbeh, A very late response on this thread, but anyway, here it is, Since all services that will be enabled on this approach works off the same Magento repository/database, and so are not 'independently deployable', this does not seem to fit into the MS architecture. Also, for ex, A order service will need to hold customer references to say who placed the order. I would think the minimal customer info will be held independently by this order service in a format of its liking.This would imply a fair bit of denomalization, which is something we will encounter when we go for a MS architecture.

Answer (score 1):

As to the microservice architecture there is SRP principle.Single Responsiplity principle.Each service has own unique responsiplity.DB schemea shouldbe decomposed also.Exporting services as rest inside a monolithic app not convert a monolithic app to micro service application.